# Gatling integration with maven

Tags: maven, gatling

I'm trying to run a [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) test within a Spring boot project but get a lot of `not found` compilation errors when I start `mvn getling:test`.

Below is also a part of my POM based on this [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/maven_plugin#maven-plugin). It seems that `Gatling` library not on the class path. But why? If I'm looking for e.g. `Simulation` in IDE (IntelliJ) after I run `mvn clean install` the class will be found.
I'm using Apache Maven 3.5.4 and Java 11.

```xml
...
<properties>
    <gatling.version>3.0.0</gatling.version>
    <gatling-plugin.version>3.0.0</gatling-plugin.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
    <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <configFolder>src/test/loadtest/resources</configFolder>
        <dataFolder>src/test/loadtest/resources/data</dataFolder>
        <resultsFolder>target/loadtest/results</resultsFolder>
        <bodiesFolder>src/test/loadtest/resources/bodies</bodiesFolder>
        <simulationsFolder>src/test/loadtest/scala</simulationsFolder>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

And here is the stack trace

```
2019-09-10 10:31:11.261 [main] INFO  io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - Compiling 1 Scala source and 2 Java sources to /target/test-classes ...
2019-09-10 10:31:12.694 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com//shop//digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:3:36: not found: type Simulation
class BasketLoadSimulation extends Simulation {
                                   ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.729 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:5:14: not found: value csv
  val nans = csv("products.csv").random
             ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.733 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:6:20: not found: type Configuration
  var config = new Configuration()
                   ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.736 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:8:22: not found: value http
  val httpProtocol = http
                     ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.737 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:12:20: not found: value exec
  val addProduct = exec(
                   ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.739 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:13:5: not found: value http
    http("add product to basket")
    ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.740 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:17:13: not found: value StringBody
      .body(StringBody("""{ "version": ${version} }"""))
            ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.741 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:19:9: not found: value status
        status.in(200, 201, 204, 206),
        ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.742 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:20:9: not found: value jsonPath
        jsonPath("$.version").saveAs("version")
        ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.743 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:24:18: not found: value exec
  val getToken = exec(
                 ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.745 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:25:5: not found: value http
    http("get token")
    ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.746 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:31:9: not found: value status
        status is 200,
        ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.747 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:32:9: not found: value jsonPath
        jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("access-token")
        ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.748 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:36:22: not found: value exec
  val createBasket = exec(
                     ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.751 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:37:5: not found: value http
    http("create basket")
    ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.751 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:41:13: not found: value StringBody
      .body(StringBody(""" {"storeId": "111"} """))
            ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.752 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:43:9: not found: value jsonPath
        jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("basket-id"),
        ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.753 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:44:9: not found: value jsonPath
        jsonPath("$.version").saveAs("version")
        ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.754 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:48:19: not found: value exec
  val getBasket = exec(
                  ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.755 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:49:5: not found: value http
    http("get basket")
    ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.756 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:53:9: not found: value status
        status.in(200, 201, 204, 206)
        ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.896 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:57:13: not found: value scenario
  val scn = scenario("basket load simulation")
            ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.896 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:68:11: not found: value flushSessionCookies
    .exec(flushSessionCookies)
          ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.899 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:70:3: not found: value setUp
  setUp(scn.inject(
  ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.899 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - /src/test/loadtest/scala/com/shop/digital/loadtest/simulation/BasketLoadSimulation.scala:73:16: not found: value httpConf
  )).protocols(httpConf)
               ^
2019-09-10 10:31:12.930 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - 25 errors found
```

Comment: Do you have the imports in the `.scala` files?

Comment: Jep. That was it. Thanks. An IDE plugin has the imports "optimized" :-(